# Expected value for a system of SDE's

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, expected-value, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $X=\{X_t: t \geq 0\}$ and $Y=\{Y_t : t \geq 0\}$ be two stochastic processes and consider the following system of SDE's:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
dX_t = a X_t \, dt + Y_t \, dW_t & ,X_0 = x\\ 
dY_t = a Y_t \, dt - X_t \, dW_t & ,Y_0 = y
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $W=\{W_t:t \geq 0\}$ is the standard Brownian motion.

Question: Determine $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$

However the question only asks for the expcted value (which I don't know how to compute), I would like to know what's the explicit solution of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating the first equation on both sides from $0$ to $t$, we get
$$X_t-x = a\int_0^t X_s \, ds + \int_0^t Y_s \, dW_s$$
and taking the expected value on both sides we get
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t]= x + a \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[X_s] ds$$
because the expected value of the Ito's integral is zero.

Then, if $f(t)=\mathbb{E}[X_t]$, we need to solve
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
f'(t) = f(t) \\
f(0) = x
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
And we know that the solution of the previous differential equation is given by
$$f(t)= \mathbb{E}[X_t]=xe^{at}$$